# Change unit increase from 1 to 10 when calculating odds ratios in r

Tags: r

I used the package questionr to calculate the odds ratios for a logistic regression model with two variables, var1 and var2. I used the code:

```
odds.ratio(mymodel, level=0.95)
```

This returned odds ratios with 95% CIs; however, I would like to report odds ratios for a 10-unit increase versus a 1-unit increase. Is there a package in r capable of doing this?

Comment: `exp(coef(mymodel) * 10)`. But it doesn't give the CI's.

Comment: as an alt to post-prcessing you can scale the predictors in the model: `model <- glm(dv ~ I(iv/10), data = df, family = binomial) ; exp(cbind(OR=coef(model), confint(model)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is searching for this in the future...just discovered the oddsratio package, which has the incr (increment) argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The odds ratio (as reported in `questionr`) shows you the odds of a positive outcome when the independent variable is 1, divided by the odds of a positive outcome when the independent variable is 0. However, by extension, when the independent variable is two, we can square the odds ratio to find the odds ratio of a two-point increase, and so on.

This means that you can raise the odds ratio (and its confidence intervals) to the power of 10 to get the odds ratio for a 10-point increase.

Let's demonstrate with a simple logistic regression:

```r
set.seed(1)

iv <- sample(100)
dv <- rbinom(100, 1, iv/100)
df <- data.frame(dv, iv)

model <- glm(dv ~ iv, data = df, family = binomial)

model
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = dv ~ iv, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           iv  
#>    -2.46465      0.04997  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  98 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       138.6 
#> Residual Deviance: 102.9     AIC: 106.9
```

Now we can see the odds ratio easily using `questionr`:

```r
questionr_or <- questionr::odds.ratio(model)
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...

questionr_or
#>                   OR    2.5 % 97.5 %         p    
#> (Intercept) 0.085039 0.025954 0.2354 9.833e-06 ***
#> iv          1.051241 1.032145 1.0741 7.070e-07 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

This shows us the odds ratio for a 1-point increase. If we want a 10-point increase, we just raise these coefficients by a power of 10:

```
questionr_or[2, 1:3]^10
#>          OR    2.5 %   97.5 %
#> iv 1.648257 1.372168 2.043965
```

You will see that this gives the same result as the `incr` argument being set to 10 in the `or_glm` function from `oddsratio`:

```
oddsratio::or_glm(df, model, incr = list(iv = 10))
#>   predictor oddsratio ci_low (2.5) ci_high (97.5) increment
#> 1        iv     1.648        1.372          2.044        10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>